# Unable to run pyspark on windows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

A bit of background:
1. Running Windows 7
2. I have python 2.7 installed
3. I reinstalled JDK 8
4. I installed Spark and followed the steps to setup the environment variables etc (refer to- https://nerdsrule.co/2016/06/15/ipython-notebook-and-spark-setup-for-windows-10/)
5. When I run spark-shell it throws a ton of errors but eventually shows me the "SPARK" logo and a scala terminal.

THE PROBLEM:-

But when I run pyspark, I get the following errors:
[image]

```html
PS C:\Users\harleen.singh> pyspark
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
17/04/04 15:18:47 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java cl
asses where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Spark\bin\..\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 43, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder\
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 179, in getOrCreate
    session._jsparkSession.sessionState().conf().setConfString(key, value)
  File "C:\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':"
```

In the python prompt that I receive, I get the following outputs:
[image]

```html
>>> sc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sc' is not defined
>>> SparkContext
<class 'pyspark.context.SparkContext'>
>>>
```

What do I need to do??

Comment: Do this-> from pyspark import SparkContext; sc = sparkContext()

Comment: it doesnt solve it. when I do sc.xxxxxxxx , it gives me error again